# Can structure with plumbing sit on floating slab?

Tags: plumbing, frost

I understand that a structure with any sort of installations coming from the ground should be anchored with a concrete footer below the frost line in order to avoid floating on frost heave, which would rip the pipes out. So when I built my detached shed some years ago, I did that and now I can have water in it all winter long, by using my frost hydrant that shuts the water off below the frost line.

I also plan to build a new home off-grid-ish. I plan first to have electricity brought in and then a well drilled. But before I start digging for a foundation, I would like to set up a mobile home as a staging dwelling. The area (Colorado) definitely freezes over the winter.

Can a structure with plumbing sit on a floating slab or on piers in an area exposed to frost? If I do set piers, how do I protect the pipe between the ground and where it enters the structure? Any additional material on improvising mobile residences with plumbing in frost conditions is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I used to live in a mobile home in Montana. The lot was compacted gravel and the home sat on a number of cinder block stacks leveled with wood wedges between the block and frame. Water and gas were connected to the home using a 2 foot length of flexible pipe. We never had a problem with frost heaving. Just be certain to insulate and run a heat tape around the water pipe and skirt the home properly. Skirting will pay for itself by your second month of heating your home.